# Add simple Paging to HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a html table that is being populated via a knockout JS foreach loop. The main reason of this method is for the functionality of the grid and binding to my MVC model for post back. I have been trying different plugins for paging but all require a datasource it seems which i can't provide. I want to use knockout for generating my table but then add paging to that table. Any ideas or suggestions? Below is a simplified version of my table.

```
<table id="AgencyTable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Address1</th>
                <th>Address2</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Zip</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="AgencyGrid" data-bind="foreach:{data: Agencies, as: 'agency'}">
            <tr data-bind="attr: { index: $index }" class="marginTopSmall">

                <td class="marginTopSmall">
                    <input data-bind="value: agency.Address1, attr: { name: 'Agencies[' + $index() + '].Address1'}" />
                </td>
                <td class="marginTopSmall">
                    <input data-bind="value: agency.Address2, attr: { name: 'Agencies[' + $index() + '].Address2'}" />
                </td>
                <td class="marginTopSmall">
                    <input data-bind="value: agency.City, attr: { name: 'Agencies[' + $index() + '].City'}" />
                </td>
                <td class="marginTopSmall">
                    <input id="StateInput" data-bind="value: agency.State, attr: { name: 'Agencies[' + $index() + '].State'}" />
                </td>
                <td class="marginTopSmall">
                    <input id="ZipInput" data-bind="value: agency.Zip, attr: { name: 'Agencies[' + $index() + '].Zip'}" />
                </td>
                <td class="marginTopSmall">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="active" data-bind="checked: agency.Active" />
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: agency.Active, attr: { name: 'Agencies[' + $index() + '].Active'}">
                </td>
                <td class="marginTopSmall">
                    <input type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeAgency, visible: agency.IsNew" value="Remove" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What's the foreach loop look like?

Comment: <tbody id="AgencyGrid" data-bind="foreach:{data: Agencies, as: 'agency'}">

Answer (score 1):

There is a great [example of this in the Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html). In that example, a `simpleGrid` [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) is used, which can be found through the same documentation page [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js).

The resulting markup is a simple as this:

```html
<div class='liveExample'> 
    <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'> </div>

    <button data-bind='click: addItem'>
        Add item
    </button>

    <button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
        Sort by name
    </button>

    <button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel.currentPageIndex'>
        Jump to first page
    </button>
</div>
```